# Maclaurin series expansion of $(x^2+1)^{-1}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider the following Maclaurin expansion:

$(x+1)^n = 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2 + \cdots $

I understand why this result is correct, because if we let $f(x) = (x+1)^n$, then

$f'(x) = n(x+1)^{n-1}$,

$f''(x) = n(n-1)(x+1)^{n-1}$,

and so forth. Substituting $x=0$ into each function to get the coefficients, we get

$f(0) = 1$,

$f'(0) = n$,

$f''(0) = n(n-1)$,

each of which correspond to each term in the original Maclaurin expansion as first stated.

---

However, my textbook then proceeds to use this result to show that

$g(x) = (x^2+1)^{-1} = 1 -x^2 + x^4 + \cdots$

Seemingly on the basis that we may simply substitute $x = x^2$ in the expansion of $f(x)$, like so:

$g(x) = 1 + (-1)(x^2) + \frac{-1\times(-1-1)}{2!}(x^2)^2 + \cdots$

$g(x) = 1 -x^2 + x^4 + \cdots$

There is no explanation as to the rationale behind this move.

In the interests of demonstrating that this operation is valid (namely, blindly substituting $x$ with $x^2$, I found the Maclaurin expansion of $(x^2+1)^n$ to yield the following result:

Let $g(x) = (x^2 + 1)^n$. Then,

$g'(x) = 2xn(x^2 + 1)^{n-1}$

$g''(x) = 4x^2n(n-1)(x^2 + 1)^{n-2}$

And so forth. One can immediately see that all derivatives will be equal to $0$, because of the x term coming outside of the parenthesis:

$g(0) = 1$

$g'(0) = 2(0)(-1)(0^2 + 1)^n = 0$

Generally, $g^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k > 0$.

Which finally gives the result that $g(x) = 1$.

But I know that the answer is not $g(x) = 1$. So, I ask, where is the problem with my reasoning?

Comment: IMO the different instances of $g$ and $n$ are confusing, I suggest that you update your question. Your first $g$ is just a geometric series. Your second  $g''(x)$ is wrong.

Comment: Is there a typo in your title? It doesn't seem to match the question. Maybe $(x^2+1)$ was supposed to be $(x^2+1)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Note that substituting $x^2$ for $x$ automatically gives a correct equality. It is also in the form of a Maclaurin series. So you need only show uniqueness of power series. Doing the computation more directly is messy because you have lots of terms vanishing at $x=0$ but you have to deal with them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I realise I made a mistake in calculating $g''(x)$, where I completely disregarded the $x$ outside of the brackets. Using the product rule,

$g''(x) = 4x^2(x^2+1)^{n-2} + 2n(x^2+1)^{n-1}$

And evaluating $g''(0)$,

$g''(0) = 4\times0^2(0^2+1)^{n-2} + 2n(0^2+1)^{n-1} = 2n$

Thus the second term in the Maclaurin series becomes

$\frac{2n}{2!}x^2 = \frac{2(-1)}{2!}x^2 = -x^2$.

Which evaluates to the expected value.